# Swap M-x and M-q

Tags: key-bindings

How can I swap `M-x` and `M-q`?

I can swap `C-x` and `C-q` with

```lisp
;; swap C-q and C-x
(keyboard-translate ?\C-q ?\C-x)
(keyboard-translate ?\C-x ?\C-q)
```

The following errors out

```lisp
(keyboard-translate ?\M-q ?\M-x)
(keyboard-translate ?\M-x ?\M-q)
```

as well as

```lisp
(keyboard-translate (kbd "M-q") (kbd "M-x"))
```

I would expect the key references (`?\C-x` and `?\M-x`) to be symmetric, but clearly something in my understanding is off.

EDIT: Reading @phils response and the referenced documentation, I can see that the above fails, at least in part, because there isn't a character in range to translate.

Thinking more about the problem, translation is probably not what I need but rather good old rebinding:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-q") 'execute-extended-command)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'fill-paragraph)
```

That is, make `M-q` call the command which is typically associated with `M-x` (`execute-extended-command`) and remap the displaced command (`fill-paragraph`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `key-translation-map`:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "M-q") (kbd "M-x"))
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "M-x") (kbd "M-q"))
```

Answer (score 8):

A control-modified letter character still results in a character, and hence character translation works for those; but most other modified keys do not result in a *character*.

```
(characterp ?\C-q)
t

(characterp ?\M-q)
nil
```

Both *are* represented as integers, but there's a limit to the ints which are valid for `characterp`.  See the following for details:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Character Codes`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Keyboard Events`

For translating key sequences generally, see:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Translation Keymaps`

Comment: +1. Good answer.